Why are personality tests deemed pseudo-scientific?
I'm particularly referring to the Myers–Briggs Type Indicator (MBTI). From a purely statistical point of view, shouldn't the fact that such tests are repeatable (to within some error margin) constitute enough evidence that they do have some scientific validity?
